# A question on multinomial theorem using binomial theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics, binomial-theorem

### $(3x^2+2x+c)^{12}=\sum A_r x^r$

and

### $\frac{A_{19}}{A_5}=\frac 1 {2^7}$

Find $c$. I really have no idea what to do with this. This was on a test. I have studied only binomial theorem. So, please use it only(combinatorics approach is always welcome).

Comment: Isn't $A_0$ a valid answer?

Comment: I deleted the other comment. Read my new comment. Side note: If you are willing to do dirty work, you always have differentiation.

Comment: 12th root.......But NO

Comment: That is cheating. The options are 4,5,6,7

Comment: OKay. Differentiation coming up.

Comment: That would be very messy i think

Comment: I know${}{}{}{}$

Comment: And by multinomial formula x^19 can be reached in various ways...adding factorials and ratio... painful job

Comment: Wait up. I have a mission. I will do this through differentiation.

Comment: Best of luck. You will need it.

Comment: I just noticed that 19+5=12*2

Comment: Okay wow. that's nice. Let me think. I am not sure, but I don't think think there is binomial like symmetry though.

Comment: $72(3x^2+2x+c)^{11}+528(3x+1)(3x^2+2x+c)^{10}$ this is the second derivative. I give up.

Comment: wolfram alpha?­

Comment: I have complete and utter faith in you. Type it in. But there *has* to be a better solution of course. I am upvoting you in hopes that someone will notice. I am trying as well.

Answer (score -1):

By comparing coefficients
$$
A_{19} = \frac{12!}{9! \cdot 1! \cdot 2!} \cdot 3^9 \cdot 2 \cdot c^2 + \frac{12!}{8! \cdot 3! \cdot 1!} 3^8 \cdot 2^3 \cdot c + \frac{12!}{7! \cdot 5! \cdot 0!} 3^7 \cdot 2^5 = 3^7\left(\frac{12!}{9! \cdot 1! \cdot 2!}18c^2 + \frac{12!}{8! \cdot 3! \cdot 1!}24c + \frac{12!}{7! \cdot 5! \cdot 0!} 32\right) \;,
$$
and
$$
A_5 = \frac{12!}{7! \cdot 5! \cdot 0!} 2^5 \cdot c^7 + \frac{12!}{8! \cdot 3! \cdot 1!} 3 \cdot 2^3 \cdot c^8 + \frac{12!}{9! \cdot 1! \cdot 2!} 3^2 \cdot 2 \cdot c^9 = c^7\left(\frac{12!}{9! \cdot 1! \cdot 2!}18c^2 + \frac{12!}{8! \cdot 3! \cdot 1!}24c + \frac{12!}{7! \cdot 5! \cdot 0!} 32\right) \;.
$$

Thus, by dividing, we get 
$$
\frac{A_5}{A_{19}} = \left(\frac{c}{3}\right)^7 \;,
$$
which implies $c = 6$ by the given condition.

Comment: Is multinomial theorem really that simple?